# About digamma function, does $\psi(a) =-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1} {n+a} ?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function, digamma-function

I am trying to learn about digamma function and it's uses. For example series, I found somewhere this solution: $$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3n+2)\left ( 3n+3 \right )} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left [ \frac{1}{3n+2} - \frac{1}{3n+3} \right ]\\ 
&=\frac{1}{3} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left [ \frac{1}{n+ \frac{2}{3}} - \frac{1}{n+1} \right ]\\ 
&=\frac{1}{3} \left [ -\psi^{(0)} \left ( \frac{2}{3} \right ) + \psi^{(0)}(1) \right ]\\ 
&= \frac{\log 3}{2}- \frac{\pi}{6 \sqrt{3}}
\end{align*}$$  I can prove the same result using a different method using integrals, but I am insterested about digamma function here, does this equality hold: $$-\psi(a) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1} {n+a} ?$$ Now I know that the RHS diverges so this can't be true. My thought is that this hold if the series is not alone(we must have like in the solution from above two parts or more inside the series). Can you help me with a proof for this?

Also here:http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html It's shown a general form for this, but of course this doesnt hold for digamma function right?

Comment: 1. This series cannot represent the digamma function since it is divergent for every $a$. 2. For a representation of the digamma function as a series, please see [the obvious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Series_formula).

Comment: It is. And? (Hmmm... did you read the link I provided? No? Why?)

Comment: Maybe we have different definitions of "to read", then.

Comment: @Zacky take a look at my answer, I hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weierstrass Formula:
$$\Gamma(z)=\frac{e^{-\gamma z}}{z}\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{\frac{z}{n}}}{1+\frac{z}{n}}$$

$$\log\Gamma(z)=-\gamma z-z+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z}{n}-\log(1+\frac{z}{n})$$

Differentiating:

$$\frac{\Gamma'(z)}{\Gamma(z)}=\psi(z)=-\gamma-1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}-\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{z}{n}}$$
$$\psi(z)=-\gamma-1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{z+n}$$

If $z\in\Bbb N^+$, this becomes a simple telescoping sum and $\psi(z)=-\gamma-1+H_z$ where $H_z$ is the $z$th harmonic number.

Furthermore, $\psi(z)\neq\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n+z}$ due to the divergence for any given $z$.

Just because $$\psi(z)-\psi(s)=(-\gamma-1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{z+n})-(-\gamma-1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{s+n})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{s+n}-\frac{1}{z+n}$$

doesn't mean that $\psi(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{z+n}$ and $\psi(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{s+n}$.

Comment: I see, now I understand, basically when we substract gamma constant and the  other part cancels out, thats why they are equal. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{n+a}$$
is blatantly divergent, the exploited identity was
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+a)(n+b)} = \frac{\psi(a)-\psi(b)}{a-b} $$
which comes from the Weierstrass product for the $\Gamma$ function.